# Can't get import working, JavaScript w/ ReactJS & ES6 / ES2016

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can you see why this is failing?

In my **./app.js** file:

```
import Howdy from ('./app/Howdy');
```

**Get this error:**
SyntaxError: /Users/elk/testapp/app.js: Unexpected token (6:18) while parsing file: /Users/carlf/Documents/dev/reactjs/FlyTweet/app.js

**/app/Howdy.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Howdy extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Howdy {this.props.name}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

If I change to using `var Howdy = require('./app/Howdy')` in **app.js** and `React.createClass()` in **Howdy.js** it works even when keep `import React from 'react'` in **Howdy.js**

Comment: why are wrapping the import inside parenthesis? it should be `import Howdy from './app/Howdy'`

Comment: get rid of the parenthesis..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax should be:

```
import defaultMember from "module-name";
```

Get rid of the parenthesis:

```
import Howdy from ('./app/Howdy');
```

should be:

```
import Howdy from './app/Howdy';
```

Check out the MDN docs on import, they are pretty comprehensive:

[MDN IMPORT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: Yep, I just noticed that. Makes me thing thrice about learning too many new languages, Java, ObjC (native dev), TypeScript (Angular2). Thanks!